# Rails: undefined local variable or method `user_params'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controllers

I'm going through https://www.railstutorial.org/ Chapter 7.

I've created a signup page for new users to put their information in. However, once the users have completed this I get an error message after I press submit.

```
undefined local variable or method `user_params' for #<UsersController:0x007fff122629d8>
```

Here is my code:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      flash[:success] = "Welcome to the Sample App!"
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'new'
        end
    end

  private

    def users_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
    end
end
```

I checked other answers, and they suggested my 'end' statements were incorrect. I've played around with them to no effect.

I think it might have something to do with my "user" or "users" but I don't know what to do :/

Thanks for the suggestions!

Comment: watch out for the typo error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had a typo :

```
@user = User.new(user_params) # should be users_params
```

You have created a *private* method called `users_params` and calling it as `user_params`. That's all the source of your error.

Comment: Thanks! I'll make sure to check on that next time :)